# Import private key on multiple computers

Tags: private-key, wallet-import

I decided to make some custom addresses for personal use and I have two computers running bitcoin clients. I imported the private key of the wallet I generated to the wrong computer and then I imported it to the correct computer. So now I have two wallets with the same public address in them. Questions are:

- What happens when I receive a payment?
- Will it take itself out of either wallet?
- Is there anything I can do to fix this?
  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incoming payments will show up in both wallets.

If you spend any of the balance, the other wallet may show a 0 balance because the "change" will only go to the wallet you sent from. The other wallet won't know about the new "change" address.

The safest thing to do is to transfer all the funds to a new address.